# matplotlib show works while savefig fails for unicode

Tags: python, matplotlib, unicode, plot

The following code produces the correct plot with `plt.show()` but fails when saved into a pdf or png image.

I have tried various suggestions (see commented lines) in similar questions, but none of them works for this case. Png file shows the unicode characters as boxes while pdf simply ignores them.

```
##-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#from matplotlib import rc
#rc('font', **font)
#rc('font',**{'family':'sans-serif','sans-serif':['Helvetica']})
#rc('font',**{'family':'serif','serif':['Palatino']})
#rc('text', usetex=True)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.plot(range(10))
plt.xlabel(u"\u2736")
plt.ylabel(u'\u03c4') 
plt.savefig('unicode.pdf')
plt.savefig('unicode.png')
#plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were nearly there when you tried changing the font family.

Only certain fonts support unicode characters. You can check which fonts you have installed via:

```
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
set([f.name for f in fm.fontManager.ttflist])
```

Then change to a unicode font, e.g. `DejaVu Sans` in Linux, `Arial Unicode MS` for Windows, `Lucida Grande` for Mac OS X, [more on Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_font#List_of_Unicode_fonts). No need to use tex:

```
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'DejaVu Sans'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. 'DejaVu Sans' doesn't exist on Mac. I tried to install it but failed somehow. But changing the font to Calibri worked for the \tau symbol. So it is definitely a font problem, as you said. Maybe you can add other font options to your answer and the ways to get information about fonts, i.e.  `import matplotlib.font_manager as fm`
`fm.findSystemFonts(fontpaths=None, fontext='ttf')`
`set([f.name for f in fm.fontManager.ttflist])`

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I didn't check on Mac. Found some resources on fonts which support unicode, so I'll update the answer